# Adam Optimizer in CNTK BrainScript

Tags: cntk, adam, brainscript

This seems to be possible using the `Python` and `C#` APIs as per the documentation.

The [`BrainScript` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/BrainScript-SGD-Block) doesn't have `Adam` as one of the options for `gradUpdateType`.

Is it possible to use the `Adam optimize`r in `BrainScript`?

Comment: Formatted content and added relevant tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry Adam optimizer is implemented in V2 CNTK only. In BS, you can use FsAdagrad which is close to Adam.

Thanks,
Emad